# Find and wrap string that contains line break

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following string:

```
You look away whilst I weave needles
through my skin to seal the scars,
running repairs, not alterations.
```

Which is actually stored in a database as:

```
You look away whilst I weave needles\r\n
through my skin to seal the scars,\r\n
running repairs, not alterations.\r\n
```

How would I find and wrap the last two lines in a span tag? e.g

```
You look away whilst I weave needles
<span>through my skin to seal the scars,
running repairs, not alterations.</span>
```

Currently I have:

```
let regex = new RegExp(stringToMatch,'m'); //I thought 'm', multiline might work?
poem = poem.replace(regex, '<span>' + stringToMatch + '</span>')
```

Which works fine for strings that don't contain any `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use something like this

```
var poem = 'You look away whilst I weave needles\r\nthrough my skin to seal the scars,\r\nrunning repairs, not alterations.\r\n';
let regex = /((.+[\r\n]+)+)((.+[\r\n]+){2})/
poem = poem.replace(regex, '$1<span>$3</span>');
```